# sql HAVING & averages

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

Learning the having clause, and averages (did AVG before), and I have to admit, I'm confused.
I'll post a problem here, one of the simpler ones on this weeks' assignment, and ask someone to explain it to me in 'real world' terminology (not the textbook language, which is sparse at best).I kinda see what I need to do, but averaging multiple values within same column has me somewhat confused, as does using 'Having' over 'Where'.

```
SQL> desc inventory
 Name
 ----------------------------
 BOOK_CODE
 BRANCH_NUM
 ON_HAND

SQL> SELECT * FROM INVENTORY;

BOOK BRANCH_NUM    ON_HAND
---- ---------- ----------
0180          1          2
0189          2          2
0200          1          1
0200          2          3
0378          3          2
079X          2          1
079X          3          2
079X          4          3
0808          2          1
1351          2          4
1351          3          2
1382          2          1
138X          2          3
2226          1          3
2226          3          2
2226          4          1
2281          4          3
2766          3          2
2908          1          3
2908          4          1
3350          1          2
3743          2          1
3906          2          1
3906          3          2
5163          1          1
5790          4          2
6128          2          4
6128          3          3
6328          2          2
669X          1          1
6908          2          2
7405          3          2
7443          4          1
7559          2          2
8092          3          1
8720          1          3
9611          1          2
9627          3          5
9627          4          2
9701          1          2
9701          2          1
9701          3          3
9701          4          2
9882          3          3
9883          2          3
9883          4          2
9931          1          2
```

Comment: What's your question? Please show the query you tried to write to solve it. The assignment you posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with averages -- it looks like it needs `SUM()` and `HAVING`.

Comment: Why did you remove the problem you're looking at, which seemed fairly clear, rather than add what you've tried? Maybe you could also explain what you think the problem is asking for, though I'm not sure this is really on-topic for this site. You need to at least demonstrate you've tried to understand it, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

You know how SELECT determines which COLUMNS to return? And you use WHERE in order to choose which ROWS will be returned? Obvious so far, right. But when you aggregate values from multiple rows together into one returned value, then you have to use HAVING if you want to perform some filtering on those.

For example:

```
SELECT author, title
FROM books
WHERE author = 'Twain, Mark'
```

would give you the list of all the books Mark Twain wrote.

And

```
SELECT author, count(*)
FROM books
GROUP BY author
```

would give you the count of books written by each author.

Finally, if you wanted only those authors who had written 3 or more books:

```
SELECT author, count(*)
FROM books
GROUP BY author
HAVING count(*) >= 3
```

I intentionally simplified the data here, but you can probably see how it applies. Another example could be to show all the authors whose books average less than $10:

```
SELECT author, average(price)
FROM books
GROUP BY author
HAVING average(price) < 10
```

If you tried to use WHERE here, all you could do is filter out rows in which the price of a single book was less:

```
SELECT author, average(price)
FROM books
GROUP BY author
WHERE price < 10
```

That would be the wrong answer of course, mostly because it would fail. But even if it returned a result, it would be the average price of all books less than $10 -- not the same at all.

Comment: Sorry, question was:    For branches with more than 25 books on hand, in branch number sequence, display branch number and units on hand.  Use the INVENTORY table.

Comment: If you mean you want all branches with a TOTAL of more than 25 physical books (10 of one title, 6 of another, 12 of another), that's one answer. If you mean a total of more than 25 DIFFERENT books, different answer. Which is the question?

Comment: MJB, multiple copies of same book, like 3 copies of same title, count as 3 books.

Comment: Assuming that the book title is not relevant to the question, then I'd use: **select branch_num, sum(on_hand) as total_on_hand from inventory group by branch_num having sum(on_hand) > 25**